# C++ Overloading the >> operator

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, iostream

I need to overload the stream extraction operator.  I need to do this by allowing a user to input a string of characters at a prompt, say "iamastring", and then the operator would extract each character from the string and test whether or not it is whitespace and if it is not whitespace store it in a character array which is then passed to an object.

@Chip et al.  For example output I am not expecting it to output anything to the screen.  Instead after a user types in a string and hits enter the user should be prompted again to enter a new menu selection.  As it stands right now the user inputs a string hits enter and then a "bad read error" is displayed and the prompt comes back up awaiting new input.

Comment: Were you a C programmer in a previous life?

Comment: operator >> is the stream EXTRACTION operator

Comment: Your buffer leaks. You should use a `std::vector` instead. That said, just use `getline` and `string`'s, like Neil suggested. Your life will be much easier.

Comment: @Paul, I was not a C programmer in a previous life I'm learning how to code with C++ and @Neil thanks for the edit :)

Comment: @GMan, what do you mean my buffer leaks?  Memory management is definitely my weakness link so I guess I don't understand how the way I have things structured would cause it to leak.

Comment: @Chip, thank you I have edited the post my actual code doesn't have it written that way I just typed it wrong.

Comment: Could you also give example output: what you expect, and what you get from the routine?

Comment: You never called `delete [] buffer`. Every `new` should match a `delete`. `std::vector` does this for you.

Comment: @GMan Thank you that was a silly mistake.  I have not used std::vector but maybe I'll take a look at it right now to see if I can pick up the syntax and functionality.

Comment: Definitely. It acts just like a normal dynamic array, but does all the nasty work for you, like resizing, etc. In fact, you probably don't need to allocate a specific size anymore. Use the `push_back` function to append a value to your array, and vector will handle the resizing for you.

Comment: So do you think if I removed the array aspect of my solution and substituted a vector instead that would solve the actual input problem?  I'm unclear as to how that would relate to the actual problem of reading in characters from the stream.

Comment: No, but it should simplify it. (Or maybe, I"m not sure)

Comment: He never posted a full code listing, so technically, we don't know yet if buffer was leaked or not, though I suspect it was.

Comment: @s1n et al., does the code logically flow?  I mean what I have posted does that look like it is taking a character from the stream character by character?

Comment: There is a couple small issues with the ifs. I don't quite like the `endoffile != true`, that would be more concise as `!endoffile`. The same goes with `isspace`, it seems simpler to read as `isspace(ch)` or `!isspace(ch)`. After checking `if ( isspace(ch) )`... then you do not need to check the opposite in the else clause.

Comment: Also you might want to check what you are doing... it seems as if you might have the inner ifs switched (have you checked whether you are storing only whitespace in the buffer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite funny - your name is like mine, but reversed :)

How about:

```
char buffer[buffSize+1]; // no need for dynamic allocation here
unsigned i = 0;
while(std::cin && !std::isspace(std::cin.peek()) && i < buffSize)
  buffer[i++] = std::cin.get();
buffer[i] = '\0'; // null termination can be important.
// i now contains the length btw
```

It's exactly your own code, just a little refactored - I removed all unneccesary stuff etc, nothing more..

Edit: Now fixed to verify stream status & prevent stack overflow :)

Edit II: Changed std::cin.good() && !std::cin.eof() to  std::cin. Btw: [why does cin have a conversion to void* and not to a bool?](http://cplusplus.co.il/2009/10/11/why-do-cin-and-cout-have-conversion-to-void-and-not-bool/)

Comment: This was helpful and clean.  I ended up with a variation on this code.

Comment: +1 – `cin.good() && !cin.eof()` can (and should!) be replaced by simply `cin`. Streams can be evaluated in a boolean context (their “freshness”) and this is canonical C++.

Comment: Konard, you are absolutly correct - I just wanted to stay as close to the given code as possible. Now edited though.

Comment: You can make this take in any length my using a `vector` + `push_back`, too.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you are not using std::string and std::getline? You should think twice or even thrice before writing your own extraction operator - formatted input is not a particularly useful feature of C++ (or of C, come to that).

Comment: Im always dubious of any training course that prevents you from using the simplest approach to the problem. I've been writing C++ code for over 20 years now, and I can count on one hand the number of times I've implemented a stream extraction operator.

Comment: Yes well we all have to pay the piper.  I guess some would call the exercise a bit on the pedantic side but there is always something to learn from banging your head repeatedly over and over again on your keyboard...I think.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, the code is broken. It doesn’t handle input failures, which may be fatal since your code can enter an infinite loop. If you encapsulate stream reading operations, you *must* take care to test whether the stream is in a valid state.

Comment: so would I want to test that ios::goodbit == true and then enter my loop?

Comment: That’s not how stream bits work. `ios::goodbit` is simply a constant. Additionally, `== true` is simply redundant. See @rmn’s updated answer for a correct (albeit uncanonical) way to accomplish this.